# The applications started by console application fail to display on desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I have a windows service called MainService, which is used to monitor SubServices. The SubServices are actually some console applications and started by the MainService via Process.Start() method. Example code:

```
var subServiceProcess = Process.Start(subService.ServicePath);
```

The SubServices work perfectly until one of them needs to start another desktop application like the MainService does. Example code:

```
var desktopApplicationProcess = Process.Start(desktopApplicationPath);
```

The desktopApplicationProcess is created and we can see it in the taskmanager. However, its GUI doesn't show. 
I've tried to run the sub service manually, and then the desktop runs correctly. So, I guess this is caused by that the sub service is started by the MainService.

Can anybody give me some sugguestion?
Thanks a lot~

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant , I am now quite sure of "session 0 isolation" causes my problem. I will try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you allowed the Service to interact with the desktop?

[image]

Comment: Yes, the MainService is allowed to interact with desktop. However, the desktop application is not started by MainService directly. So it doesn't work.

Comment: @allentranks what is the account your subservices are running under?

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I don't know how to set account for the sub service since it's actually a console application.

Comment: @allentranks What about the user that is logged in? See if this [MSDN Link Helps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.100).aspx) The Service Applications versus Other Visual Studio Applications Section

Comment: I've tried the user which is logged in and seems doesn't work.. :(

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? That checkbox will not work as advertised on Windows Vista and beyond because of [Session 0 Isolation](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation) as Hans commented.

Comment: @CoreTech thank you very much, the post you provided is helpful! My os is Windows 7 64bit. I've recurred the dialog like this picture: http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/interactive-services-detection-dialog.jpg